# ViewPager- fetching images from parse.com

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I need to fetch images and texts from Parse database. I can get it from drawable folder but problem is to get it from parse. Here all the images are stored in drawable folder but how can I download all the images from parse & store it in a folder. Shall I use path to get urls of the images? Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Declare Variables
ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter adapter;
String[] rank;
String[] country;
String[] population;
int[] flag;
UnderlinePageIndicator mIndicator;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from viewpager_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);

    flag = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india,
            R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia,
            R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.nigeria,
            R.drawable.bangladesh, R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.japan };

    // Locate the ViewPager in viewpager_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    // Pass results to ViewPagerAdapter Class
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this, rank, country,
            population, flag);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // ViewPager Indicator
    mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setFades(false);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

    }
 }
```

ViewPager Adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
// Declare Variables
Context context;
String[] rank;
String[] country;
String[] population;
int[] flag;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] rank, String[] country,
        String[] population, int[] flag) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.country = country;
    this.population = population;
    this.flag = flag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rank.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    // Declare Variables
    TextView txtrank;
    TextView txtcountry;
    TextView txtpopulation;
    ImageView imgflag;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);

    // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
    imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem getting it from Parse, or do you just now know how to?

Comment: @MariusFalkenbergWaldal  I'm having problem getting images from parse because I'm not able to find a way to store the path of the images in a string variable and then to display it.

Comment: Why do you need to store the path of the image? If you store the image on the Parse platform, it is stored as a PFFile that you can use with i.e. a PFImageView

Comment: Since you're on Android, the terms are probably different. PFFile if probably ParseFile? But the concept will be the same.